# Uncaught TypeError: $.getScript(...).done is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, getscript

I faced a weird situation here..

.

Below code is working:

```
// this code working perfectly

$.getScript( "https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js" ).done(( script, textStatus )=>{
    // run something
});
```

.

.

But if I put the whole code inside `setTimeout` it will give error in `browser console`

```
// this will give error in browser console

setTimeout(()=>{
    $.getScript( "https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js" ).done(( script, textStatus )=>{
        // run something
    });
}, 4000);
```

and it will give `error` in `browser console`:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the error in question?

Comment: Telling us which error would be a good start.

Comment: The error is in the title i guess Uncaught TypeError: $.getScript(…).done is not a function

Comment: i just editted the question....

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a sandbox like https://codepen.io/pen ? The code works just fine

Comment: Could you kindly share more information? Maybe a live snippet? Overall I think something is going on between that promise and setTimeout. Guessing they have different execution context? dunno. however.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when update Bootstrap v4.0 to v4.3.1

To fix it you need to use jQuery without `slim` postfix. (Use `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` instead of `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js`)